# Configure WampServer for non-Latin web adresses

Tags: php, wordpress, wampserver, right-to-left

I have installed WordPress locally on WampServer for testing purposes. I discovered that when I changed the permalinks structure to reflect post title (the title is in my native language 'Urdu'), and requested the following page in browser

```
http://localhost/blog/طوفان-اور-سیاست-دان/
```

it returned a 404 error which said

```
The requested URL /blog/Ø·ÙˆÙØ§Ù†-Ø§ÙˆØ±-Ø³ÛŒØ§Ø³Øª-Ø¯Ø§Ù†/ was not found on this server.
```

I am using WampServer 2.2 and WordPress 3.4.

Since many PCs don't have an Urdu font installed, here is the image of first address for you.
[image]

The English translation for urdu part is "Storm-and-politicians" . Urdu, unlike English, is written from right to left.

How can I configure my local web server to accept web adresses in Urdu? Many sites including the Urdu wikipedia use this scheme.

Comment: Your webserver *is* accepting this web address. It looks more like that your wordpress instance is not properly configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to learn more about this problem:

Each time you see apache giving you a not-found message, you will find an according entry in the error log of your webserver. It contains more information what happens behind the scenes.

For example you will see a message similar to this one:

```
File does not exist: C:/.../htdocs/blog/\xd8\xb7\xd9\x88\xd9\x81\xd8\xa7\xd9\x86-\xd8\xa7\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1-\xd8\xb3\xdb\x8c\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb3\xd8\xaa-\xd8\xaf\xd8\xa7\xd9\x86
```

This is useful because it allows you to see the binary sequence the apache webserver uses to query your file-system for the file.

You can turn this into a PHP string to decipher it:

```
echo "\xd8\xb7\xd9\x88\xd9\x81\xd8\xa7\xd9\x86-\xd8\xa7\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1-\xd8\xb3\xdb\x8c\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb3\xd8\xaa-\xd8\xaf\xd8\xa7\xd9\x86";
```

Depending in which encoding you view this output, it can look like the following:

```
UTF-8     : طوفان-اور-سیاست-دان
Ansi      : ÏÀ┘ê┘üÏº┘å-Ïº┘êÏ▒-Ï│█îÏºÏ│Ï¬-Ï»Ïº┘å
ISO-8859-1: Ø·ÙˆÙØ§Ù†-Ø§ÙˆØ±-Ø³ÛŒØ§Ø³Øª-Ø¯Ø§Ù†
```

Apart from having this looking differently, the question is why does the webserver not find this file?

As you write you use wordpress, you probably just have missed to enable these type of URLs, in Wordpress jargon those are called ["Pretty" permalinks<sup>*Codex*</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks).

Comment: Your comment solved half of the problem and answer provided me with enough info to resolve the remaining half. After some searching through WordPress docs i found that i need Apache to load mod_rewrite module which in,by default, commented out in WampServer. So the problem was solved just by removing a '#'

Comment: Yes you need `mod_rewrite` for these wordpress "Pretty" permalinks. Great to hear you solved the issue.